# Laptop keyboard and touchpad working in Windows but not Linux

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, laptop

I have a HP Spectre x360 that was originally running Windows before I put Ubuntu 18.10 on it about 9 months. Everything was working fine until last week when the internal touchpad and keyboard stopped working.

So far I've discovered that the touchpad and keyboard work in the bios and Windows but not on Ubuntu 18.10, Ubuntu 19.04, Ubuntu 16.04, or Arch Linux.

I've reinstalled the operating system multiple times. Any help would be appreciated.